# How to show tags in the history view of egit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have a repository with some dangling commits:

```
o (master) commit 3
o commit 2
o
| o (tag: danglings) dangling commit 2
| o dangling commit 1
|/
o commit 1
o initial commit
```

I have tagged the lastest dangling commit with a tag, to make sure it doesnt get lost, just in case i need it at some point in the future.

However, when viewing that repository in egits history, i dont get the dangling commits. They are simply not shown. When i create a branch that points to `dangling commit 2` the two commits including the tag are shown.

How to prevent that? I want to see **everything**, not only branches in egit's history view.

EDIT: Added a nice screenshot montage:

[image: screenshot montage]
The first one shows master checked out, and no dangling branch exists. Of course, the dangling commits **and** the `dangling`-tag exist!

On the second one i created a branch called `dangling` that points on the commit tagged with the tag `dangling` and checked it out.

Note that the view doesn't change (except for the bold written `master` and the `HEAD` getting moved) when i check out master on the second picture.

Comment: Could you put a screenshot of what you see when you have switched to your new branch?

Comment: Note: a fix is in progress in Egit, thanks to [robinst](http://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst). See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18742256/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst) mentions in the comments:

> This was simply a bug in EGit and happened only with annotated tags, please see [bug 417655](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417655) which proposes [the fix](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/16619/) in [`org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.history.GitHistoryPage`](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/16619/1/org.eclipse.egit.ui/src/org/eclipse/egit/ui/internal/history/GitHistoryPage.java).
>   Target Egit 3.1

---

Original answer:

This Egit exercice discusses the History View:

[image: https://raw.github.com/stefanlay/gittraining/master/exercises/egit/git/history-view-6.png]

Consider the different button available in this view:

[image: https://raw.github.com/stefanlay/gittraining/master/exercises/egit/git/history-view-buttons.png]:

That tutorial mentions:

> TIP: If you got lost with the different filters and the history doesn’t show what you expect, set it back to show everything.
>   Therefore make sure that '`Show all branches and tags`' (`a`) is turned on and '`Show all changes in repository`' (`e`) is selected.

Those two buttons should potentially show you all *reachable* (that is at least tagged) commits.

---

The "[Filtering settings](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Filter_settings)" section of the [Egit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) is clear:

> The next four toggle buttons in the view toolbar control how the displayed commits are filtered with respect to the current input.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/0/01/Egit-0.9-history-view-config.png]

> The buttons are working as radio buttons, i.e. one of the four buttons must always be down.
>
> - If the "`Repository`" button is down, the commit log is not filtered and shows all commits reachable from the currently checked out branch (or all commits, see below about the "All Branches" action)
> - If the "`Project`" button is down, the commit log is filtered to show all commits which affected any of the resources in the project containing the current input
> - If the "`Folder`" toggle is down, the commit log is filtered to show all commits which affected any of the resources in the parent folder of the current input
> - If the "`Resource`" button is down, the commit log is filtered to show only commits which affected the current input; the view menu item `Show > Follow Renames` allows to toggle whether renames of the selected resource should be followed by this filter
>
> Note that not all combinations of filter setting and current input are meaningful; for example, if the current input is a project, the "Project" option is in fact the same as the "Resource" option.

But the "[All branches](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#All_Branches)" sections add:

> This toggle activates the "All Branches" mode.
>   **By default, only those commits are shown in the commit log that can be reached from the currently checked out commit, i.e. the Commit Graph ends with the currently checked out commit and newer commits are not shown.**
>   If this button is down, all commits will be shown in the commit log.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c7/Egit-0.9-history-view-allbranchesToggle.png]

In your case, I am not sure commits are show when referenced by a tag alone.
Only branches make those commits visible.

Comment: I have already selected both of them. Still, the tagged-but-not-reachable-from-a-branch commit isnt shown.

Comment: @Oznerol256 then I am afraid only branches make those commit visible. I have edited the answer to include other relevant sections of the Egit User Guide.

Comment: `git log` is certainly able to make commits visible based on a tag. So the conclusion is, **egit history isnt as good as `git log`**

Comment: @Oznerol256 I agree: it seems to be "branch-oriented" only.

Comment: This was simply a bug in EGit and happened only with annotated tags, please see [bug 417655](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417655) which proposes the fix.

Comment: @robinst Looks great! I have include a complete reference to your fix in the answer for more visibility.